# Should I put this in my controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my attend method below currently in my controller. My question is how do I know whether to put this in my event or user model vs. my events controller? I am also going to add another method remove_attend which will do the opposite of attend. At what point do I put these methods into a model?

```
 def attend
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @event.users.include?(current_user)
      flash[:error] = "You're already attending this event."
    else
      current_user.events << @event
      flash[:success] = "Attending event!"
    end
    redirect_to @event
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It belongs to the event controller. Flash messages or redirects cannot be put in the models. So, when you see either, it's safe to assume that they are controller material.

It belongs to the event controller because the resource that attend refers to is an Event. You can create, edit or attend an event, in that sense.

Comment: so let's say I need a method to remove the relationship between a user and an event...and I need this method available both in the event and user view/controller...should I put this in the events helper? where would this belong?

Comment: Ideally, this should belong to the event model. You should have a remove method on the even model. Then, a user can call that method using an association proxy like user.event.remove. This is the beauty of Rails :)

Comment: last question: I made a remove_attendance method in the event model. Should I call that method straight from the view, or should I put a controller in between?

Comment: Definately not in the view. Put it in your controller and create an instance variable to show in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave this code in the controller. If you start accessing User attributes in this code (e.g. checking the type of user or the number of events they're already attending), then it might be a good idea to move that code into the user model.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the controller, the model should only be called upon to edit or retrieve data.

from what i'm seeing it looks like you're referencing an object (current_user) that isn't a property of the class you calling the method from, this shouldn't happen in the model.